# Javascript function to find total page height

Tags: javascript, dynamic, background, height

I'm after a simple javascript function that will detect the total height of my web page which is dynamic and apply it to the height of a div which is the page background. Would it be possible to implement it?
   The div is called bg...
   Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try scrollHeight  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollHeight

Comment: ah yeah he wants the whole height, not just the viewport. Good call @Dampsquid

Comment: thanks for that, not sure if it's compatible with ie8 though...

Comment: So doing <script type="text/javascript">
   function findheight(){ 
   var intViewportHeight = window.innerHeight;

   bg.style.height = intViewportHeight;
   }
 </script>  doesn't seem to work... I have the body set out like so...   <body onload="javascript:findheight;">   Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099015/stuck-with-simple-javascript-function-to-find-height#comment17803070_13099015

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to figure out the height of content in iFrame for the purpose of adjusting it properly.

```
var body = document.body,
html = document.documentElement,
height = 0;

height = body.offsetHeight;
if(height === 0){
     height = html.offsetHeight;
}
```

The reason for checking the `body` first is that the height of `html` is actually the height of the iFrame, which could be bigger than the content itself. However, in certain cases such as when `body` has no height, then it falls back to use height of `html` instead.

For your case, you might want to experiment with a similar scheme. I'm not sure why you have to use a `div` to set background so I can't really suggest a better alternative (if any).

---

Solution based on the comment below:

What you can do is the following. Have a div inside the main container with position absolute, width/height 100% and z-index -1. Then it will always be the correct size no matter how large the contain grow or shrink. With this approach, you will have to make sure that container always has size. This is a pure CSS solution, which might be simpler than using Javascript to adjust.

Comment: It's because it's not a full width background. The page has a full page background image using supersized, onto which is laid this center background using an svg which has a fixed width...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var height = body.offsetHeight ? body.offsetHeight : html.offsetHeight;
document.getElementById ('divID').style.height = height + 'px';
```

Here an useful documentation:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html

Comment: Looks like this should work, but I'm having trouble implementing it...I'm putting it in the head, with a body "onload..." followed by my div "bg"...Is this the right order?

Comment: '<script type="text/javascript">
   function findheight(){ 
   
   var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
   document.getElementById ('bg').style.height = height + 'px';
   }
  </script>
  


  
 </head>

 <body onload="findheight()">
  
  <div id="bg">'  This isn't working.

Comment: What's the result you are getting ? There are many ways for a code to "not work". Can you post URL where we can see it ?

Answer (score 0):

Im using currently following code to do that:

```
var getBodyHeight = function () {
    var d = document,
        bd = d.body,
        dd = d.documentElement,
        max = Math.max(
            bd.scrollHeight,
            bd.offsetHeight,
            bd.clientHeight,
            dd.offsetHeight,
            dd.scrollHeight,
            dd.clientHeight
        );

    return max;

};
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var height = screen.height;
var width = screen.width;
var resolution = width+"x"+height;
alert(resolution);
```

it gives the resolution of the screen.i know you want page height and width but it will help you later in web development. i am using it as most important part for my web!

Comment: `window` has no `height` method.